# ASP.Net Identity in Azure Cloud

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-identity

I have a problem with ASP.Net Identity used in application scaled to two instances. It seems that we have problem with checking password (checking hashes?) or verifying generated tokens (for example: password reset). When application works on one instance, then everything seems to be fine. It's weird because I read that using ASP.Net Identity in Azure cloud should be safe - it should use the same machine key on both instances.

Our user manager use token provider created below:

```
public DataProtectorTokenProvider<ExternalUser> Create(string purpose = "GeneralPurpose")
        {
            var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider(_appName);
            var result = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ExternalUser>(provider.Create(purpose));
            return result;
        }
```

What is more, our user manager is singleton, but I think it shouldn't be a difference.

Any idea why it doesn't work on two instances in Azure? I will appreciate any help or advice.